# The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference

Tags: web-services

I am getting this error while creating the WebService Client.

```
[ERROR] The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) /TestServices/services/index.jsp
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) /TestServices/services/index.jsp
```

Any could advice me

Answer (score 1):

You are addressing a Java Server Page, not a Web Service, with that 'endpoint'.  I think only you can determine what the correct endpoint address will be without more information.